# Possibility of customizing bicycling layer in Google Maps and using with custom map style

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am creating a cross platform mobile app with a web view that displays a custom Google Map I am initializing and styling in JavaScript using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

My hope was to highlight bike trails using the [Bicycling Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#BicyclingLayer).

However, there are two issues I have run into:

1. I am also custom styling the roads/trails that the bike layer also affects using the styles property in the map options passed to Google when I load the map tiles:

   ```
   var mapOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.761732,-95.388371),
       mapTypeControl: true,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       styles: mapStyles, // JSON to style the map
       zoom: maxZoomLevel,
       zoomControl: false 
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

   var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
   bikeLayer.setMap(map);
   ```

   However, the styling seems to cover/override most of the bike layer because the trails are highlighted in only a few of the spots they should be and only at some zoom levels.  **Is it possible to use the bike layer with custom map styling on the roads/trails as well? Could I somehow get the bike layer to appear on top of my custom styling?**
2. I would also like to customize the bike layer itself, such as changing its color. However, there doesn't seem to be options for it built into the API or any way to interact and manipulate the request, which is http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@221000000,bike&src=apiv3&hl=en-US&x=3850&y=6771&z=14&s=G&apistyle=s.t%3A2%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ff9ebf3a%2Cs.t%3A6%7Cs.e%3Ag.f%7Cp.c%3A%23ff22b4c3%2Cs.t%3A3%7Cs.e%3Al.t.s%7Cp.v%3Aoff%2Cs.t%3A51%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ffffffff%2Cs.t%3A50%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ffffffff%2Cs.t%3A49%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ffffffff%2Cs.t%3A51%7Cs.e%3Al%7Cp.v%3Aoff%2Cs.t%3A2%7Cs.e%3Al%7Cp.v%3Aoff%2Cs.t%3A4%7Cp.v%3Aoff%2Cs.t%3A5%7Cp.c%3A%23ffd8e2da%2Cs.t%3A1%7Cp.c%3A%23ffd8e2da%7Cp.v%3Aoff%2Cs.t%3A33%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe2ece4%2Cs.t%3A34%7Cp.il%3Atrue%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe2ece4%2Cs.t%3A35%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe2ece4%2Cs.t%3A39%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe2ece4%2Cs.t%3A1%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe2ece4&style=59,37%7Csmartmaps

   When I delete 'bike' from lyrs=..., the effects of the bike layer disappear. When I remove certain parts or all of apistyle=..., the bike layer is revealed underneath. **Basically, I don't see a way I can get to and customize Google's bike layer. Is it possible?**

Comment: Just to follow up, I continued working on this, and as of August 2013, it was not possible. It was, at that point, a new feature, so hopefully it will become more customizable over time.

Comment: Wow, it has been 10 years.  It still looks the same.  Cmon Google, Maps is supposed to be a core application, not a hobby.  People will use it, why is it so hard to keep improving it?  I still cannot do something as simple as hide regular roads from the bike layer and only show trails